# Hadoop - No such file or directory installation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation

I have installed hadoop just now in ubuntu .

When I go to hadoop folder (to check hadoop is installed properly or not) through terminal and write this ..

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

it gives me this error ...

```
bash: bin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: That is simple, you don't have your environment set up correctly. How did you install Hadoop? What does you $CLASSPATH look like? What does $HADOOP_HOME look like? go back and make sure you set all your PATH's correctly.

Comment: Yes I did that ... Now I think I messed up with JAVA_Home .. it is not giving me JVM .. Stuck there .. do you know any other way around?

Comment: No, you need to have your CLASSPATH and HADOOP_HOME variables set correctly. Post what you added to your .bashrc profile for HADOOP variables and your JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably too long to answer but here is solution

If everything is correct, you should try

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

not

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

sbin/start-all.sh is the right command and this command is deprecated.

To start the namenode and data node use the following command,
sbin/start-dfs.sh
sbin/start-yarn.sh

Also run the jps command to check if the namenode and datanode daemons are started.

If the namenode and datanode point to the same id then there will be problems when you execute mapreduce examples.

For further information on how to appropriately install and start the daemons, refer to [myhobbyandexperiments.wordpress.com](http://myhobbyandexperiments.wordpress.com) .

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
start-all.sh
```

Step2:

```
start-yarn.sh
```

Step3:To check name node and data node are running or nor

```
jps
```

Step4:

```
hadoop version
```

Hope it should work fine....